# create Azure release pipeline using ansible

Tags: azure-devops, ansible, azure-pipelines, ansible-template

Whether ansible can be used to create release and build pipelines in azure is there any existing or custom modules for creating pipelines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is yes. Ansible can be used in azure devops pipelines.

You can click [here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscs-rm.vss-services-ansible&targetId=72d0c402-3bd0-4b8a-b56c-1ed5cade77d0) to install Ansible extension in your azure devops organization. After it is installed, you can use Ansible task in the pipeline to run playbook.

To get started with azure devops pipeline.  You can check out [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/create-first-pipeline?view=azure-devops&tabs=java%2Cyaml%2Cbrowser%2Ctfs-2018-2).

You can check below detailed tutorial about using ansible in azure devops pipeline.

[Automating Infrastructure Deployments in the Cloud with Ansible and Azure Pipelines](https://www.azuredevopslabs.com/labs/vstsextend/ansible/)

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply. ansible in azure devops pipeline tutorial you have shared they created new linux vm and through that vm it's deployed. Can we do that without creating new linux vm

Comment: In above link, they created a new linux vm to show how to configure Ansible in a Linux machine. If you have your own machine, there is no need to create a new linux vm. You can just follow the steps to configure Ansible in your machine and configure the SSH service connection in your azure devops project.

Comment: hi this answer works fine but i need to know like can we use azure agent to run our playbooks like without using any vm's.

Comment: It seems ansible is preinstalled in [azure devops cloud agent](https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments/blob/master/images/linux/Ubuntu1804-README.md).  You can have a try using the ansible installed on the cloud agent without using any vm.